# InterProject communication in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, dynamic-linking, xcode-workspace

My project architecture is, a workspace which has two projects(Project A & Project B). Project A has three more sub projects(Project X , Project Y, Project Z).

- Workspace

  - Project A

    - Project x
    - Project y
    - Project z
  - Project B

Project B is more a kind of utility project. It needs to be re used in Project A, Project x,Project y, Project z and elsewhere it could be. I am starting to do a prototype. But face challenges in linking Project B in other projects. Every time i need to add the .a file manually into all other projects. Do we have any solution to dynamically link?

I tried this approach as well. I moved project B inside Project A below Project z. But i was not able to access the classes in Project x, y, z because all the projects are in the same level.

Any solution to dynamically link projects in the same level?

Comment: Kindly let me know if this approach is feasible? Anyone has worked on similar requirements?

Comment: Did you try CocoaPods?

Comment: @Visput - No i haven't tried with that... Would that be the optimal solution?

Comment: Yes, it will easily manage your situation.
If you want I can provide example of how to configure it to handle your scenario.

Comment: @Visput could you please share an example

Comment: Not taking the bounty *(@Visput, are you willing to write a step by step tutorial on SO?)*, the idea is to transform one or more .xcodeproj into **Pods**, starting with `pod spec create`, then create a `Podfile` at the client level, pointing to a local directory. Some documentation on https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html

Comment: thank u.. will try it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add Project B as Target Dependency from Build Phases to other projects, that way Project B is built and added to other projects just as you'd like.

Comment: I am not able to add it Project B as Target Dependency for Project A. If projects are in the same level, we are not able to make one dependent of another, Only if a Project is inside another project, we can make the parent project dependent on child.